# Set default value of Bool in C++ through complier

Tags: c++, boolean

I'm trying to make some changes on an opensource C++ projects.
I know that the value of BOOL in C++ should be initialized when declared, otherwise it will be unexpected. But almost all of the bool variables in the origin codes are uninitialized declared like this

```
bool oracle_pro_decl;
bool _oracle_external_procedure;
bool _oracle_language_procedure;
```

I'm using GNU C++ as complier, is there a way to set all the default value of bool to false?

Comment: `are uninitialized declared like this` Are they declared at _file scope_?

Comment: Yes, they are declared at head files.

Comment: You probably know wrong. Consider reading a [good C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) then see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Comment: `I know that the value of BOOL in C++ should be initialized when declared, otherwise it will be unexpected` is imprecise. Not initialized variables will have indeterminate values. But there are cases where variables are default initialized. `at head files` What is a "head fille"? Identifiers defined at [file scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope#Namespace_scope) have [static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) and are [zero initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

Answer (score 3):

> I'm using GNU C++ as compiler, is there a way to set all the default value of bool to false?

If you do so, you are changing the [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) of C++. Read the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) and see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) website.

**However, you might code your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) doing so** (implicitly initializing every `bool` [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) to false). Your plugin would work at the [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) level.

#### My opinion is that coding such a GCC plugin would be a bad idea.

My recommendation is to enable more warnings and debugging info, that is to compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/) debugger (and perhaps [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/)). Once your program has few bugs, you might ask GCC for more optimizations (e.g. with `-O2`)

You could also consider using the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).